# Magento 2 Images not showing in Frontend

Tags: magento-2.0

I installed Magento 2 on a new fresh installed VPS, running Debian 8. Magento is installed and I can seem to be working OK, but I cannot see any images on the front end and when I look in the catalog.

I'm running Apache 2.4, PHP 5.6 and MySQL 5.6

Comment: you need to check if images actually on the server...

Comment: I followed the path from within chrome inspect elements and the images are there, the permissions are correct too, but stil the images do not show up. The Luma Logo, css etc all show in the front end and all the css and images on the backup show too. It's just  the images in the front end that don't show. thanks

Comment: Follow steps according to below to show images http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/92485/4342

Comment: You can find the answer of the problem here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/97230/34408

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/157769)

Comment: Hi @Joe check media url in database 'web/unsecure/base_media_url' SELECT * FROM `core_config_data` WHERE `value` LIKE '%%'

Answer (score 1):

Your Static Contents are most likely out of date. You can regenerate your static contents with this command on your server from your **Magento 2 root folder**. Note that you may or may not need to delete files from `pub/static/frontend`

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy <locale>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to run these commands on the root of the project:

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
chmod 777 -R .
```

Comment: Note that the last line of this answer sets up very unsafe permissions. You should NOT be setting permissions to 777 on a production environment.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will happen if you use the Windows platform instead of Linux.

Because in Magento 2 recent release, they have introduced the Symlink option (Like shortcut of an existing file) to copy from code directory to pub directory.

Unfortunately, the Windows platform needs special permission to create symlink files. So you need to stop your server and your command prompt terminal then we need to **start the server and terminal with the administrator access**.

Then simply **delete "*adminhtml*" and  "*frontend*" folders from** "***pub/static***" directory.
Then do setup upgrade using

> php bin\magento setup:upgrade

Flush the cache once using

> php bin\magento cache:flush

I hope the problem is resolved now. If it works kindly give me Thumbs up.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try:
**php bin/magento catalog:images:resize**

If you are using Watermarks for your images, also ensure that the Watermark Image(s) are in place by checking pub/media/catalog/products/watermark/default/

Sometimes, running the catalog:images:resize will ensure the images are in place. If/when using watermarks, if they've been accidentally removed, it breaks regenerating products.