# Magento 2 CSS and JavaScript not loading from correct folder

Tags: magento2, installation, magento-2.0, windows, static-content

I am attempting to install and run Magento 2 on WAMP on a Windows 7 machine with little success.

After jumping through the many and various hoops to get the site to load I am now faced with 404 responses and no styles or javascript loading.

Spec is as follows:

- Magento-CE-2.0.0+Samples
- Apache 2.4.9
- PHP 5.5.12
- MySQL 5.6.17

When I look at the browser console among the errors are attempts to access files that are not in the pub/static folder.  The "frontend" folder does get loaded and most of the files are present.  I have noticed however that some CSS files are not present.

On running the PHP deploy command

*`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`*

that is mentioned in other posts I get the below error. I am not sure how to remedy this?

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate  64 bytes) in
>   C:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\oyejorge\less.php\lib\Less\Visitor.php on
>   line 45

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I bumped up the PHP memory allowance and ran the PHP deploy script again.  This time it did not error and executed fully.  However, the same issue as described above is still present.  The site loads but every attempt to load any page or asset results in a 404 page not found an error with no styling applied.

Please see below the errors in Chrome Inspector.

[image]

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara This question was asked first, is well formed, has good answers, so IMO the other question is a dupe candidate, not this one... B.t.w., if the flag on the other question as a duplicate to this one was turned down, it is not necessary to flag this question as duplicate of the other to try to achieve the same.

Comment: See S.A's answer, too – a fresh Magento installation is in "default" (not "production") mode and does not need the static content deployed, which is what you're being told to do in all the other answers.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

**SOLUTION # 1 (IF YOU WANT TO EDIT XML FILE)**

I would like you to download Magento 2 zip from `magentocommerce.com/download` with sample data, create a new **db** in **phpmyadmin**, extract zip in **htdocs** folder. Install Magento 2 but do not use **localhost** use **127.0.0.1** in-store URL and admin URL. After successful installation **DO NOT** run magento.

Now we are going to clear / delete caches and sessions of Magento 2. Go to following paths and delete everything:

```
ROOT > var > cache > *DELETE ALL*
ROOT > var > page_cache > *DELETE ALL*
ROOT > var > session > *DELETE ALL*
```

When Magento 2 is not in production mode, it will try to create symlinks for some static resources on the local server. We have to change that behavior of Magento 2 by going to edit the `ROOT > app > etc > di.xml` file. Open up `di.xml` in your favorite code editor, find the `virtualType name="developerMaterialization"` section. In that section below, you will find an item `<item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">` which needs to be modified. You can modify it by changing the following content:

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink
```

To:

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy
```

Now last step, also delete old files generated in `ROOT > pub > static > DELETE ALL EXCEPT .HTACCESS`

**SOLUTION # 2**

Install Composer. Now I would like you to download Magento 2 zip from `magentocommerce.com/download`, create a new **db** in **PHPMyAdmin**, extract zip in **htdocs** folder. Install Magento 2 but do not use **localhost** use **127.0.0.1** in store URL and admin URL. After successful installation **DO NOT** run Magento.

Now we are going to verify Composer installation, Deploy static content, clear / flush Magento cache, and reindex the Magento 2 blocks. To perform all the above actions, press WINDOWS KEY + R to open the RUN dialog and type “cmd” to open Command Prompt.

Type “**cd PATH_TO_YOUR_MAGENTO2_FILES**” to enter in Magento 2 ROOT directory.

Now to verify Composer installation in above directory, type “**composer install**”.

> If you get any error in this step, please check your Composer
> installation

In this step, we are setting up static content to deploy on our Magento store. To perform this, type “**php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy**”.

For Those who are on **Magento 2.2.x**

> **`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`**
>
> If you get any error, check your PHP.EXE and PHP.INI Environment
> Variable

Clear / Flush Magento cache by typing “**php bin/magento cache:flush**” in CMD.

And finally, to Reindex Magento Static Blocks type “**php bin/magento indexer:reindex**”.

You are done with the successful installation of Magento 2.

Comment: Also in php.ini change **max_execution_time** to 500, **memory_limit** to 2048M, **post_max_size** to 2048M, **upload_max_filesize** to 2048M and **max_file_uploads** to 2048.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.  I have made these changes but they have had no effect.  I restarted WAMP server after making the changes. I have edited the question to show the errors that I can see in the Chrome inspector

Comment: Oh i am sorry to mention one more thing, first delete all cache and session, make changes in **di.xml** and also delete everything from **ROOT > pub > static > DELETE ALL EXCEPT .HTACCESS**

Comment: @E.Gain see edited answer

Comment: Hi, I have done this and still no change

Comment: Do I need to run the PHP deploy AFTER clearing all of the cache and the pub/static folder?

Comment: i would like you to download magento 2 zip from https://www.magentocommerce.com/download with sample data, create new db in phpmyadmin, extract zip in htdocs folder. install magento 2 but do not use **localhost** use **127.0.0.1** in store url and admin url. after successful installation do not run magento, first clear cache and session, edit di.xml file and then enter magento 2 url in browser. this is the actual way to install magento 2 on localhost

Comment: @E.Gain your welcome :)

Comment: this is the most craziest solution to this issue...

Comment: @MagenX well but it works :)

Comment: lol, sure it works, you can open a can of beer using hammer, or you can pull off the tab on the top.... see the difference in your solution?? we dont need a hammer to open it...

Comment: @MagenX This is every person's view that which tool he more prefer to use. In your eyes, you criticize everything as hammer rather than sharing your view of solution.

Comment: Answer has been edited.

Comment: If you set a default language other than en_US you need to deploy static files for that language specific:
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy nl_NL en_US

Comment: Can I use localhost after successful installation or it may cause problem later?

Comment: @BhojendraNepal I would suggest you to use 127.0.0.1 rather than localhost since other applications may bypass it.

Comment: I've tried both solution #1 and #2 here to install Magento 2 on Windows but always get the unstyled css and 404's. I detailed the way I thought it should be done here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139054/why-does-the-web-based-install-of-magento-2-on-windows-7-localhost-using-xampp-a but no one answered and I still cannot get Magento 2 on Windows no matter how I try. I only want it for local development, I have working Linux installs. I used 127.0.0.1 but can't understand why for some that works in place of localhost and if its recommended anyway.

Comment: Solution #2 worked like a charm, thank you for saving me hours if not days, dealing with this issue!

Comment: @JonathanMarzullo your welcome!

Comment: loy shy..... :)

Comment: #Soluation 2, working all step as you have given, but page not found error gating

Comment: Still, i am facing the error empty page, may i know other possibilities of error.

Comment: @FayyazKhattak Did you ever faced this error : https://snag.gy/oI9DjQ.jpg, How can i solve the error Refused to apply style and MIME Type

Answer (score 17):

you just need to update the apache2.conf file.

On Ubuntu 16.04

1. Open and edit the file `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`
2. Navigate to the place in the apache2.conf file `<Directory /var/www/>`
3. Change  `"AllowOverride None"` to `"AllowOverride All"`
4. Save the file
5. Restart `apache2 -> sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: It was so hard to find this answer! Everywhere else people suggest (re-)deploying static content even though a fresh Magento installation is in "default" (not "production") mode and does not need the static content deployed.

Answer (score 14):

For me it was simply because mod_rewrite wasn't enabled.

`sudo a2enmod rewrite`

and

`service apache2 restart`

Answer (score 13):

**Here is the simplest solution if showing version name in css path**

like : pub/static/version323334/

then run this query in mysql

```
INSERT INTO core_config_data (path, value) VALUES ('dev/static/sign', 0)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = 0;
```

after that clear the config cache

```
 bin/magento cache:clean config
```

you can also disable static file version from admin

[image]

Comment: This worked for me thank you. However, query needs to be fixed  INSERT INTO core_config_data (path, `value`) VALUES ('dev/static/sign', 0);

Comment: what is path and values

Comment: path, value are fields name  i already define values ( dev/static/sign , 0) , just run this sql it should be work

Answer (score 11):

If you are facing problem of css and js page load design after installation in magento2

please follow the following step-:

open the terminal and navigate to magento web root

```
 $ cd /var/www/html/magento2
```

Step 1.

```
 $ php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Step 2.

```
$ php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Step 3.

make sure apache “rewrite_module” is enable and then restart the server

Step 4.

```
$ chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/magento2
```

Step 5.

```
 $ chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/magento2
```

Step 6.

delete cache folder under var/cache

The above step working. I hope this will work for you also.

Let me know if any issue. :)

http://gotechnies.com/css-javascript-files-loading-magento-2-installation/

Comment: how run these commands in windows ?

Comment: "Let me know if any issue" - doesn't work on Windows.

Comment: It works for me just for first 3 steps. :)

Comment: It works perfect in 2.2

Comment: Not so smart to set permission to 777 for all files on the server.

Comment: I'm not really impressed with the step where you gives full read write permission to the entire magento installation.

Comment: setting permissions to 777 is bad advice but hopefully any sysadmins will know better.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue resolved by adding

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Modify this

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

to this

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

you should also enable the `mod_rewrite` and insall ssl certificates apache2 module:

```
sudo a2enmod ssl

sudo a2ensite default-ssl

sudo a2enmod rewrite

sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 5):

1. Try to disable cache if you do not disable it before
2. Make sure you have the latest version of Magento with clean code. If
   you modify or customize something make sure fix all errors.
3. Run several commands below may help you.

   `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

   `php bin/magento cache:flush`

Remove folders in

- `pub/static/frontend/*`
- `var/cache`
- `var/view_preprocessed/*`
- `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Answer (score 3):

In my case I accidentally deleted `.htaccess` file from `ROOT/pub/` and `ROOT/pub/static`folders. Then it is started working when I **revert it back**.

Answer (score 2):

Solved !!!

Run following commands in CLI interface of your Magento2 root folder:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Then delete **var** folder by this command at your root of magento2.

```
rm -rf var/*
```

Then refresh your homepage and admin panel. Its Working !!!!! Cool !!!!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with 404s. I solved it by making sure the VirtualHost directive in Apache was correct. Here is my VirtualHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/magento2
    ServerName magento-ce-2.1.6
    <Directory "/var/www/magento2">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: And can you also tell, what was wrong before? Otherwise this example won't be much help to others.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue as the OP and it was simply because I set my locale to `en_AU`, so using the default deploy command only generated the `en_US` content. You have to add the locale you are actually using to the EN of the command, like this:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US en_AU
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to execute below commands in your cmd :

```
  php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

  php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Answer (score 1):

See this post http://infoeverysolution.com/index.php/2020/01/16/magento-2-css-nd-js-not-loading-issue/. This is an issue with pub folder htacess file if its missing.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by following these steps by BlueOrchidd:

https://community.magento.com/t5/Installing-Magento-2/Magento-2-Installation-Worst-Experience-Ever/m-p/23786#M382

One important thing: Dont change Locale to anything that en_US. after installation deal with that ..

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above solutions. But it didn't help me. Despite, I used the same commands which they mentioned with the changes of sequence. They are,

1. **clear cache, composer_home, generation, log, page_cache, tmp and view_preprocessed** from **var** directory
2. run the following commands one by one.

> php bin/magento indexer:reindex
>
> php bin/magento cache:flush
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

I hope this may help to someone like me.

Answer (score 0):

Disable mod_pagespeed

Pagespeed processes a "cached" instance of your content with an abbreviation, i.e if this is the normal file.

> image.css

It will be set as follows.

> image.pagespeed.css

The above is a very simply example, but already you can see where the underlying issue is. This can cause improper static content loading due to not being able to be found via the core pathing, due to the fact that those are temporarily. This is an inherit problem with Mod_Pagespeed, ergo why we advise keeping it disabled.

the ansewer of fast comet support, and it solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic). I have used following steps for for the static files to load correctly.

After installation is complete:

Make sure apache module 'rewrite' is enabled if not then do following

- `cd /etc/apache2`
- run command `a2enmod rewrite`
- `sudo vi /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

Then make following changes

Modify from:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride None
     Require all granted
</Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Then restart apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

or

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Then change the permissions for `<magento root director>`

- `chmod -R 774 /var/www/html/<magento root director>`

Then deploy the static content

- `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f` (-f is required if you are in development env)

Then flush the cache and reindex

- `<magento root directory> php bin/magento cache:flush`
- `<magento root directory> php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

OR

- `<magento root directory> rm -R /var/cache*`

Then access your home page using

- `127.0.0.1/your_configured_url` instead of
  `localhost/your_configured_url`

Answer (score 0):

Ditch composer and install using the latest zip from [here](https://magento.com/tech-resources/download)

That did the job for me

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the problem is that .htaccess gets deleted after deploying static content. So, to fix it, just get a copy of the file from [Magento official docs](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/pub/static/.htaccess). Also, very important to run the static deployment command in production mode. The problem happens to me every time I'm doing the static content deployment in developer mode.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i found and solved the cause of the problem:

First, check the "View Page Source" of your webpage. Find the .css file link and click it. If you find 500 internal error, that means some .htaccess file is causing the problem. Try to follow the .css file path in your magento project and you will find that .css file does not even exist there.

How to solve this? Go on and remove the `.htaccess file from pub/`. Now run Click thesourceJust remove the `.htaccess file from pub/` then run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`.

This should resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you tried everything above and didn't succeed , you probably installed magento in a subdirectory in your webserver , which will lead to 404 on assets , what you should do is open the .htaccess in your pub/static find the next lines :

```
## you can put here your pub/static folder path relative to web root
RewriteBase /magento/pub/static/
```

you should notice that the value of RewriteBase should be relative to your web root .. adjust the value for your server configurations (start from the folder containing and don't forget the "/" as the first character ...

Answer (score 0):

@haim's solution worked for me

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

and

```
service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Check .htaccess file is available in pub/static folder.If you don't have that file than you can download it from https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.4-develop/pub/static and upload in your directory pub/static.

Answer (score 0):

after searching a lot , conclude by using these 2 commands. my problem is same and solved.
1:php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
2:php bin/magento cache:clean