# Static files seems to be present but returns 404

Tags: magento2, css, install

I have just installed Magento to my webserver and deployed static files. However, when I access the site it is shown without any styling, and I get a lot of 404 errors for the static files:

`/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/da_DK/mage/calendar.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/da_DK/requirejs/require.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/da_DK/css/styles-m.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/da_DK/mage/requirejs/mixins.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/da_DK/css/styles-l.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
/pub/static/_requirejs/frontend/Magento/luma/da_DK/requirejs-config.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
styles-m.css:24 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
styles-m.css:26 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/da_DK/images/logo.svg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/da_DK/css/print.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/da_DK/mage/requirejs/mixins.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
/pub/static/_requirejs/frontend/Magento/luma/da_DK/requirejs-config.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/da_DK/requirejs/require.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/da_DK/css/print.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/da_DK/mage/calendar.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/da_DK/css/styles-l.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

When accessing the FTP I have verified that most of the files are there, however some of them are looking a little weird:

[image: does require.js look like a shortcut?]

[image]

Apache rewrites are turned on, and the presence of the following line in .htacess should be enoug to enable it, I belive? (CentOS/WHM)

`RewriteEngine on`

Any suggestions to what might be going on?

Comment: It sounds like you may have deleted the .htaccess file that lives inside of pub/static dir

Answer (score 1):

Using your SSH terminal go to folder `/pub/static/` and run the following command to set folder and files permissions:

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \; && find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

**Note** that this command is for linux.

Answer (score 0):

Install Composer. Now I would like you to download Magento 2 zip from `magentocommerce.com/download`, create new **db** in **phpmyadmin**, extract zip in **htdocs** folder. Install Magento 2 but do not use **localhost** use **127.0.0.1** in store URL and admin URL. After successful installation **DO NOT** run magento.

Now we are going to verify Composer installation, Deploy static content, clear / flush Magento cache and reindex the Magento 2 blocks. To perform all above actions, press WINDOWS KEY + R to open RUN dialog and type “cmd” to open Command Prompt.

Type “**cd PATH_TO_YOUR_MAGENTO2_FILES**” to enter in Magento 2 ROOT directory.

Now to verify Composer installation in above directory, type “**composer install**”.

> If you get any error in this step, please check your Composer
>   installation

In this step, we are setting up static content to deploy on our Magento store. To perform this, type “**php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy**”.

> If you get any error, check your PHP.EXE and PHP.INI Environment
>   Variable

Clear / Flush Magento cache by typing “**php bin/magento cache:flush**” in CMD.

And finally, to Reindex Magento Static Blocks type “**php bin/magento indexer:reindex**”.

You are done with successful installation of Magento 2.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Can you elaborate why this would work?

Comment: I already mentioned it, When magento 2 is not is production mode, it will create symlinks for external resources like js css img files on local or external servers. By modifying its behavior, will leave you with perfect magento 2 running store.

Comment: See this as well: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97209/magento-2-css-and-javascript-not-loading-from-correct-folder/97230#97230

Comment: Thanks. I will try it out and then return if it doesn't work. Might take some time though - I haven't been able to get the installer running by cloning git or unpacking files directly on server, so I need to unpack on my computer and upload the 50 thousand files one at the time..

Comment: Why you are uploading 50k files? Just upload zip as it is you are going to download from magentocommerce and then extract it on your server. Do not unpack it on your computer.

Comment: Every time I do that I can't access the installer for some reason. I will give it another try though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34342/discussion-between-muhammad-fayyaz-uddin-khattak-and-user2806026).

Comment: you dont have to do all these changes, just use proper permissions and check your server configurations.

Comment: @MagenX proper permissions are granted, server configurations are more than good. If you don't have any solution, please do not suggest anything without reading.

Comment: here is exact place to debate, if you look into his screenshot you will see that permissions and owner wrong, some files 777 other 666, owner UID set as 520, other files as 0 (root). this is completely wrong setup. as 99% cpanel setups... your solution as many others suggesting to dig into core files are wrong, dude this is a fresh default setup, dont make me laugh ok?

Comment: Answer has been edited.

Answer (score 0):

to me you just have some weird cPanel/Apache configuration, plus to this you have incorrect permissions. this is the only problem... remember that now default magento installation will ALWAYS work out of the box. also it looks like your ftp program incorrectly uploaded some files.
do not upload files from your computer, upload zip archive to your server and unzip it to your web directory, apply proper permissions and set correct owner.
this is required and very important, because the default cPanel installation usually creates suPHP setup which is very strict to UID/GID.

remove all cache and static files (dont worry about .htaccess cause it has .<-DOT it will not be removed even if you run `rm -rf *` in that directory. usuallly :)
when you deploy static files also use proper user/owner:

```
su <FILES_OWNER_NAME> -s /bin/bash -c "bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy"
```

also to be safe, files permission must be 644 and the folder permission must be 755.

Comment: Thanks! I am currently in the process of chmodding pub/static 755 recursively to all subdirectories, and slowly things are beginning to work on the page, even though the process isn't done yet. Will anything bad happen by having these files 755?

Comment: I might try your suggestion instead - it seems more right than recursively forcing permissions. How do I figure out who the owner should be?

Comment: Could it just be root?

Comment: no :)  see your server config or parent folder like /home/USER_NAME/ or in WHM "List Accounts".

Comment: Thanks. My WHM user for this installation is called magento. However, when I run the following command from SSH:
su magento -s /bin/bash -c "bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy"
I get an bash: bin/magento permission denied. Is it because im logged in to ssh as root and not magento?

Comment: file must be executable `chmod +x bin/magento`