# "404 page" and CSS problems after successfully completing Magento2 installing wzard

Tags: magento2, configuration, css, installation, 404-page

folks,

I am working on **Ubuntu 14** and I followed [this short video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B_UkjDFmQqI) to install **Magento2**. I've also used some installation guidelines from Magento website.
I've passed the readiness check successfully and I have completed the installation also successfully with no errors or even one warning.

**Now the problems that I'm facing**:

- When I try to open **http://127.0.0.1** this opens a broken, not organized, not aligned, and **not formatted page**. I did a search on the net and I found that it is a **problem related to something called CSS**, which I don't know what it is and how to fix.
- If I try to open **127.0.0.1/admin** (and I'm sure that the link is correct) I get that **404 Not Found page**!

For god sake help :( ... I've been working on fixing this for a week!
But **Please use simple words and detailed steps**; as I'm not deep in IT things ... when you suggest a solution please tell me exactly how to do it ... when you want me to change something in any file or any configuration, please tell me where it is exactly or how to find it.

thanks in advance

Comment: Follow this solution. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97209/magento-2-css-and-javascript-not-loading-from-correct-folder

Comment: OK now I have manged to solve the admin page part and it is now opening, and that is by adding the following to the 000-default.conf file ..... <Directory /var/www/magento2>
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
 AllowOverride All
 Require all granted
</Directory> ............. but still the page formatting and the CSS problem is there!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have url rewrite issue

Go to Database in "core_config_data" table there is "web/seo/use_rewrites" set it to 0.

after that clear cache:

```
bin/magento cache:flush
```

reindex all:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, then restarted apache, but it did NOT solve any of the issues .... so I retruned "web/seo/use_rewrites" to 1

Answer (score 0):

I am newbie i had similar issue . Was able to resolve this issue by below steps.

`php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
Or
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f` 


`Update apache.conf
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride none
Require all granted
with
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted

Restart apache server
Replace the .htaccess file
Delete pub/static/* Except .htaccess files
Delete 
var/generation/* var/cache/* var/page_cache/* var/view_preprocessed/* var/composer_home/cache/*`

Download the htaccess files from below link
   http://lovetomarry.com/packages/Magento.zip

Answer (score 0):

Copy .htaccess from your magento `pub` directory and paste in `root` directory for 404 error.