# 404 not found magento 2 static and media files not loading

Tags: magento2, 404, base-url

[image: **resources not loading after changing base url**]
resources not loading after changing base url. i have tried changing base_url for media files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento 2 CSS and JavaScript not loading from correct folder](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97209/magento-2-css-and-javascript-not-loading-from-correct-folder)

Comment: my problem is that magento is looking directly in root floder for media and static files. it is not looking in pub/media folder

Comment: Check the presence of .htaccess file inside pub/static.  While Deleting the files under pub/static to get rid of any existing symlinks, we need to be be careful not to delete the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 2):

Magento 2.2.2

Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)

I tried:

```
rm -rf pub/static/* generated/* var/page_cache/* var/cache/* var/view_preprocessed/*
chown -R apache:apache .*
find . -type d -exec chmod 0770 {} \;
find . -type f -exec chmod 0660 {} \;
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Found out the pub/static/.htaccess file was missing. Added it back in and static content showed up.

Answer (score 2):

Sometime it is a hosting settings issue - its try to find "static" folder directly in magento root "/" but not in "pub/"

To fast fix it try to make symbol link in magento root directory

$ ln -s pub/static static

Answer (score 1):

In your magento root directory run the below command..

for windows system:
`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

For Linux/Ubuntu:
`bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in magento 2, Ubuntu 16.04. You can resolve it by running the following command in your magento 2 root directory

> sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

In case it gives a warning and fails, run the above command forcibly, like,

> sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Post this step, you will have to compile magento setup once again. So, run the following command.

> sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Answer (score 1):

Many of the answers here are good, but all are pieces in a puzzle where there are many such pieces... Therefore, you may need to work through several of the answers on this page to solve your issue.

I am using Apache as well and simply found I needed to enable mod-rewrite for the rewrite rules in the htaccess file(s) in the pub directory to work.

Answer (score 0):

None of this worked for me. The problem was apache. Needed to set `AllowOverride All` in the virtualhost due to Magento's many many .htaccess files.