# Frontend CSS faulty

Tags: magento2, css, frontend, sample-data

I know this question has been set a few times now, I can't seem to find the answer - I did the whole cache emptying of folders with "php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy" - this seems to only work for reloading the backend css properly but not the frontend. (I had this problem with the backend in the beginning, but the content:deploy worked it out, just doesn't seem to be doing anything for the frontend).

The frontend looks bogus, the css file reference of the page seems correct... http://localhost/magento/pub/media/styles.css (at least, there is a file here).

I'm on a local Xampp (Win 8) Community Version wit Sample Data included.

Thanks for the help.

....

[image]

Comment: have you set developer mode, php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer and remove var folder

Comment: tried this...nothing, sorry. :(

Comment: have you set client mode inside stores-> Configuration->Advanced -> Developer -> workflow type to client side

Comment: I just did this, and repeated your first step...now my backend is missing it's CSS file: 

FileError: 'http://localhost/magento/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/css/styles.css' wasn't found (404)

in styles.css ---- which I just populated again from my backup. But not, this isnt working for the frontend

Comment: It just seems as if the css in media/styles.css is not being loaded properly... I just dont get it, the link is there <link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" href="http://localhost/magento/pub/media/styles.css" /> ... but the frontend css folder of LUma theme is empty...I dont know if this has any effect.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing this problem admin gives 404 error and frontend didn't attach css(i.e. Luma didnot showing in proper format..).so i did these steps to solve these both problems in magento 2. 
1)go to terminal and run this command

```
sudo gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

And change:-

```
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride none
Require all granted
```

To

```
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
```

only change AllowOverride none to all

And

2) go to terminal and run command :-

```
    sudo a2enmod rewrite
    sudo service apache2 restart
```

Then give the permission to your var,pub and app/etc. and then go to your admin and frontend it works properly.i think it works for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this **Before that take Backup**

1. Remove everything, except `.htaccess` file from `pub/static` folder
2. Open up `app/etc/di.xml` find the path `“Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink”` and replace to `Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy`

**Note**: Remove entire files and folder under pub/static except `.htaccess` file.

For More info ref this http://www.dckap.com/blog/magento-2-admin-links-not-working-in-windows/

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply...it seems the backend looks better now, I can see all the products fully generated within the dashboard, but I am sorry, it's not doing anything for the frontend - still looks the same. I was wondering though...what you mean with remove everything under pub/static except .htaccess .....htaccess is OUTSIDE in the folder pub, but not /static.... I hope I wasn't misunderstood - my backend admin panel is working, its the frontend WEBPAGE that doesn't seem to be loading the theme/skin/css.

Comment: delete  all file under pub/static excetpt .htaccess

Comment: Okay... I did this.... [link](http://imgur.com/IOwSCJ4) - is it correct? deleting everything IN pub/static but leaving all in /pub

Comment: Now it's working or not

Comment: my question is, what about the other folders and files in the pub folder? /errors, /media, /opt, cron.php, get.php, index.php, static.php? Remove these too? or JUST pub/static?

Comment: just pub/static

Comment: I deleted pub/static files, I corrected di.xml from “Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink” to Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy --- still the same... sorry :(

Comment: clear your cache & Session

Comment: I just flushed magento cache and deleted cache folders in var, nothing happens...root folder magento url is still not styled.... I have no idea what the problem ist. ;(((((((((
Thank you for the replies anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this answer worked, it is however necessary to do this during installation and before starting Magento (I am guessing the system creates faulty links afterwards which can't all be reversed?) - basically I needed to reinstall Magento with new database... another post solved this problem very well, in Solution #1:

*https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/97230/39395*

**SOLUTION # 1**

I would like you to download Magento 2 zip from magentocommerce.com/download with sample data, create new db in phpmyadmin, extract zip in htdocs folder. Install Magento 2 but do not use localhost use 127.0.0.1 in store URL and admin URL. After successful installation DO NOT run magento.

Now we are going to clear / delete caches and sessions of Magento 2. Go to following paths and delete everything:

ROOT > var > cache > *DELETE ALL*
ROOT > var > page_cache > *DELETE ALL*
ROOT > var > session > *DELETE ALL*

When Magento 2 is not in production mode, it will try to create symlinks for some static resources on local server. We have to change that behavior of Magento 2 by going to edit ROOT > app > etc > di.xml file. Open up di.xml in your favorite code editor, find the virtualType name="developerMaterialization" section. In that section below, you will find an item  which needs to be modified. You can modify it by changing the following content:

Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink

To:

Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy

Now last step, also delete old files generated in ROOT > pub > static > DELETE ALL EXCEPT .HTACCESS