# Magento 2 shows 404 error and front end css crashed

Tags: magento2, css, frontend, static-content-deploy

I have installed Magento 2 successfully.

When i am trying to open front end that looks like this picture and backend shows 404 error. how to solve this?

[image: CSS error on frontend]

Comment: Please check server if `mod_rewrite` enable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Deploy static content using Magento 2 CLI. If you don't know how to do it, I have written everything in the answer below with the reasons why this happens and how to solve it. Please check it out:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/97230/34408

Comment: Thanks @Fayyaz. I tried your solution #2. Front looks well but backend results 404 error. i have cleared cache and done reindex also.

Comment: I think you should try installing Magento 2 again with the method I defined because, with my Solution # 2, people get benefit from it. It must be an issue with files. Try installation again.

Comment: Also, one more thing. In php.ini file, change max_execution_time to 500, memory_limit to 2048M, post_max_size to 2048M, upload_max_filesize to 2048M and max_file_uploads to 2048.

Comment: only home shows the contents well. The other pages like sign in, create account, contact us etc are shows 404 error.

Comment: I have installed another fresh magento 2. done the same things like [this](http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/97230/34408). Occurs the same issue now also.

Comment: Finally need to enable module rewrite in wamp. Now it will work. check [this link](http://velanapps.com/install-magento-2-in-wamp-server/)

Comment: @SaravananDS great at least you solve the issue. Yes the rewrite module is necessary for Magento 2.

Comment: Afer Deploy static content, still my website looks like above screen shot.... May i how to solve this question.

Answer (score 10):

After static content deploy my js and css not loading because in url deploy version is added so  insert Query in my database.

```
INSERT INTO core_config_data (scope, scope_id, path, value) VALUES ('default', 0, 'dev/static/sign', '0');
```

Or in Admin below screenshot setting static file settings
[image]

I hope this will work

Solution : 2
Permission issue so correct your permissiom first of all 
Command in your teminal

```
chmod -R 777 var pub
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Solution: 3 Deploy according to your language.

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US nl_NL -f 
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Answer (score 6):

I hope this will help you

If you are using wamp server on windows then

`C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12>php.exe C:\wamp\www\<Magento root directory>\bin\magento setup:static-content:deploy in your CLI`.

Comment: remove cache and try again

Comment: its work for me, if developer mode enables then use -f with command

Answer (score 5):

have been in the same situation, and concluded it was because of deleting htaccess file also in pub/static.

If using some VCS you can recover it easily or as indicated in [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/136883/51034) go to the official Magento2 repository and retrieve your missing file.

Answer (score 2):

You need to deploy static content.

Run

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

From your root

Comment: @ashish Thanks for your reply. I have tried this. after this process front shows as well. but backend results the same 404.

Comment: Did you tried to clear the cache??

Comment: yes @asish. i have cleared cache using `php bin/magento cache:flush` and done reindex using `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`.

Comment: @ Saravanan DS  Try string replace i mentioned  at the answer ( /app/etc/di.xml ) Then clear the cache, setup upgrade.

Comment: yes done the same thing also in `  /app/etc/di.xml `. now also same error.

Comment: @asish only home shows the contents. The other pages like sign in, create account, contact us etc are shows 404 error.

Comment: Afer Deploy static content, still my website looks like above screen shot.... May i how to solve this question.

Answer (score 1):

Run these commands below, it normally resolves many issues including that.

```
alias mage="php -d memory_limit=-1 -f bin/magento"

chmod -R 775 pub/static/ var/ pub/media/ &&
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/ var/cache/ var/page_cache/ var/tmp/ var/generation/ pub/static/frontend/ ;
php -r "opcache_reset();"
mage cache:flush &
mage indexer:reindex &
mage setup:static-content:deploy;
mage setup:upgrade &&
mage setup:db-data:upgrade &&
mage dev:source-theme:deploy &&
chmod -R 775 pub/static/ pub/media/ var/
```

Answer (score 0):

Run below command in your current root ( mage22 )

php magento setup:static-content:deploy

Just Open the

MAGENTO_ROOT/app/etc/di.xml

and replace below code form line number around 574

```
<item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink</item>
```

replace

```
<item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy</item>
```

Clear cache, deploy static content and check now.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you have added new code or made any change in code then you have to compile the code for that you can run the following commands :

1) Go to your Magento project root directory.
2) sudo rm -rf var/cache var/generation var/di 
3) sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade 
4) sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile
5) sudo chmod 777 -R var/

after this can restart your server

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

and see your admin panel hope it would be running.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still having issues loading backend (admin portal), - for me it was always throwing a 404, its just a matter of changing the AllowOverride directive from "none" to "all" in the respective document root.

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all>
</Directory>
```

And finally, restart apache/httpd and load your site again !

Answer (score 0):

if you are using xampp server use bellow command in your cmd to load static files:

```
D:\xampp\php> php.exe D:\xampp\htdocs\<Magento root directory>\bin\magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```