# Messy Frontend to Magento2 after Install

Tags: magento2, css, installation

I am still seeing a messy frontend on my Magento 2 after my install was complete. I don't know if this is a css problem. I fixed the symlinks problem and now I am able to log in to the admin site. I have done the redeploy command and reindexed the site. Still, the site does not display correctly. It opens with a bullet-point menu of the site. What should be done?

Comment: Check permissions. Clear `var` directory except `.htaccess` and re-run deploy command

Comment: check my question this may help you. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/121312/magento-2-shows-404-error-and-front-end-css-crashed.

Comment: Check this link too. http://velanapps.com/install-magento-2-in-wamp-server/

Answer (score -1):

When you're editing stuff, just set the files to 777 :

find . -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;

find . -type f -exec chmod 777 {} \;

---

When you're done, set them back to recommended values :

find . -type f -exec chmod 400 {} \;find . -type d -exec chmod 500 {} \;

find var/ -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \;

find media/ -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \;

find var/ -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \;

find media/ -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \;

Comment: there is no need to set `chmod 777`, just make sure correct `user` runs `php`...