# Accidentally deleted .htaccess file inside pub/static folder

Tags: theme, css, .htaccess, less

I accidentally deleted my .htaccess file. Before that I could just delete everything in the `var` and `pub/static` folder (except the `.htaccess` file of course) and just reload the page to see my CSS / LESS changes. Without the `.htaccess` file the stylings completely disappear. Now I always have to run the `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` command in order to see my changes which takes for ever. Is there any way I can re-setup the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: You can download corresponding file from the [official Magento 2 repository](https://github.com/magento/magento2).

Comment: I was glad to help :) I will add the comment as the answer.

Comment: I marked it as correct :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can download corresponding file from the [official Magento 2 repository](https://github.com/magento/magento2). That will solve your problem.

Comment: Does .htaccess needs be present in the directory if using nginx ?

Comment: @Zoya you don’t need it without Apache

Answer (score 1):

You can find the .htaccess file from below path :

> https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.4-develop/pub/static

Hope it may help you!

Answer (score 0):

1. You can find the `.htaccess` file at `magento root/var`
2. There is one more `.htaccess` file you can find in `root/` directory named as `.htaccess.sample`

Get the file into your root directory.

Remove the cache and try.