# Magento 2 setup:upgrade error

Tags: magento-2.1, upgrade

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade -vvv
Cache cleared successfully
File system cleanup:
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type Closure as array in /var/www/croquenoix/dev/croquenoix/web/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php:1288
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/croquenoix/dev/croquenoix/web/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(1013): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->cleanupGeneratedFiles()
#1 /var/www/croquenoix/dev/croquenoix/web/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/UpgradeCommand.php(72): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->updateModulesSequence(false)
#2 /var/www/croquenoix/dev/croquenoix/web/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php(257): Magento\Setup\Console\Command\UpgradeCommand->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#3 /var/www/croquenoix/dev/croquenoix/web/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(874): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#4 in /var/www/croquenoix/dev/croquenoix/web/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php on line 1288
```

The stack trace is not long enough for me to figure where the error really comes from. How can I see a longer stack trace? How can I debug this error?

Comment: I have the same issue. after upgrading to Magento 2.3.1 and the cause is that there is an extension that is not compatible with Magento 2.3.1 then I disabled it and there it is now fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It must be issue in any custom extension, Please try to remove your custom extension and try to install them one by one. It works for me. May be helpful for other.

Comment: it turns out this was the case. an extension I had recently installed caused this. I removed it and the error went away. after I have upgraded the Magento 2 version to the latest and then was able to reinstall the extension and did not have the error this time.

Comment: You mean `bin/magento module:disable` or complete REMOVE using composer remove?

Comment: Just disable the modules

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade --keep-generated
```

Answer (score 1):

Please run below commands :

```
 1. rm -rf generated/
 2. sudo chmod -R 777 generated/
```

then run di compile command :

```
 php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
    We recursively delete the folder **var/cache** and **generation/** . In the generation folder, what is created when run the `bin/magento setup:di:compile.`

```
sudo rm -rf var/ generation/
```

Grant the rights to the current directory

```
sudo chmod -R 0777 .

sudo bin/magento setup:di:compile

sudo bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Comment: Can you explain what it does?  It's helpful to know what it is doing before running it, and explanation could help more people learn what to do in similar but not exact situations.

Comment: Ok, sorry ) one minute .

Answer (score 0):

1. 1st delete var/cache and generation folders
2. run command :

   ```
    sudo bin/magento setup:upgrade
   ```
3. give full permission to :

   ```
   sudo chmod -R 0777 var/ pub/ generation/
   ```
4. and run below command :

   ```
    sudo bin/magento setup:di:compile
   ```

Comment: What will happen if he deleted  .htaccess in pub folder?? Do you know?

Comment: ir you deleted .htaccess  file the page not loaded properly...please refer below link for your more clarification ......https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/136879/accidentally-deleted-htaccess-file-inside-pub-static-folder