# Refused to apply style "because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type"

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, css, admin-panel

Suddenly CSS is not loading on my Magento 2 admin panel. The frontend is working fine.

Error details:

```
1.  "Refused to apply style from 'https://www.ornativa.com/pub/static/version1502029409/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/css/styles-old...' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

2 ."Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at callback ((index):68)
at Object.execCb (require.js:1650)
at Module.check (require.js:866)
at Module.<anonymous> (require.js:1113)
at require.js:132
at require.js:1156
at each (require.js:57)
at Module.emit (require.js:1155)
at Module.check (require.js:917)"
```

[image]

Comment: anything done with the server or .htaccess file?

Comment: Same problem i'm facing

Comment: Did you solve your issue?

Comment: this may help https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/121312/magento-2-shows-404-error-and-front-end-css-crashed/284023#284023

Comment: I had this issue just now, but it was due to indicating the the wrong module in the layout/default.xml where I was referencing this, fixed that and this was fixed

Answer (score 23):

Recently had a very similar issue with a Magento 2 site. Managed to track down the issue to a very important .htaccess file missing in the pub/static folder on the server.

It's unclear how this file was mysteriously removed but re-adding this file from a clean Magento 2 installation rectified the issue.

Answer (score 16):

The problem is caused due to the permission issue on the static files.

To fix this issue,

1) Go to file path `pub/static/`

2) Check whether `.htaccess` file is available (hidden file - Press cntrl+H to view it).

3) If not available, based on the Magento version get `.htaccess` file in the file path `pub/static/` and move into your server.

4) Finally, clear your browser and Magento cache and check it.

Comment: I dont check htaccess file :D perfect! :)

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue this morning. I updated *Sales email templates*, then suddenly admin pages stopped working.

**The problem was solved when I re-deployed the assets for admin pages.**

I run these commands:

1. `grunt clean; grunt exec; grunt less`
2. `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f -s standard`
3. `bin/magento cache:clean`

Maybe, the CSS has to be re-deployed whenever the *Sales email templates* are updated. yea noob

Comment: Could you please explain what the `grunt` commands do? I don't currently use it. Thanks!

Comment: @JoshuaFlood maybe this link can help you and the others ..
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html

Comment: @JoshuaFlood grunt is just a way to automate recurring tasks like in this case compiling less file into css, but you could go over a whole project without using grunt, in my case used compass for compiling sass

Comment: Thanks guys! Though I'm not sure that I want to tamper too much with the magento system right now as I'm almost done setting up my production environment and I've read that Magento will no longer support LESS in the near future, so I'll wait until they've got their act together. Will have to play around at some point.

Comment: @JoshuaFlood, where did you read that magento will stop using LESS? Is this still current?

Comment: You can also just execute `grunt refresh` instead of `grunt clean; grunt exec; grunt less`

Answer (score 7):

Spend about an hour looking for solution to this problem...

I had fresh **Magento ver. 2.2.6** installation and had the same problem. None of the answer currently here worked for me. Finally a simple:

`php bin/magento cache:flush`

fixed my problem.

I hope the above will come to rescue if all the other tips fail.

Answer (score 4):

enable the rewrite_module of apache

Comment: You mean : apache httpd.conf the line : LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

Comment: yes run this command to enable the apache rewrite mode, **_sudo a2enmod rewrite_**

Answer (score 4):

If you are in production mode, enter this command

**bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy**

If you are in developer mode, enter these commands in order

**1- grunt exec
2- grunt less**

Answer (score 4):

I also had the same issue,

What I did was to rename the .htaccess on both the root directory and /pub directory. it fixed my problem.

Also, you can replace .htaccess with this

```
############################################
## uncomment the line below to enable developer mode

#   SetEnv MAGE_MODE developer

############################################
## uncomment these lines for CGI mode
## make sure to specify the correct cgi php binary file name
## it might be /cgi-bin/php-cgi

#    Action php5-cgi /cgi-bin/php5-cgi
#    AddHandler php5-cgi .php

############################################
## GoDaddy specific options

#   Options -MultiViews

## you might also need to add this line to php.ini
##     cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
## if it still doesn't work, rename php.ini to php5.ini

############################################
## this line is specific for 1and1 hosting

    #AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
    #AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php

############################################
## default index file

    DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>

############################################
## adjust memory limit

    php_value memory_limit 768M
    php_value max_execution_time 18000

############################################
## disable automatic session start
## before autoload was initialized

    php_flag session.auto_start off

############################################
## enable resulting html compression

    #php_flag zlib.output_compression on

###########################################
## disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security.c>
###########################################
## disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload

    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

############################################
## enable apache served files compression
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

    # Insert filter on all content
    ###SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    # Insert filter on selected content types only
    #AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript

    # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

    # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

    # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
    #BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

    # Don't compress images
    #SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

    # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
    #Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

############################################
## make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode

    SSLOptions StdEnvVars

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    #RewriteBase /magento/

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

############################################
## redirect for mobile user agents

    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobiledirectoryhere/.*$
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobiledirectoryhere/ [L,R=302]

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>


############################################
## Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides
## If you still have problems, use the second line instead

    AddDefaultCharset Off
    #AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/html A0
    ExpiresByType text/plain A0

</IfModule>

###########################################
## Deny access to root files to hide sensitive application information
    RedirectMatch 404 /\.git

    <Files composer.json>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files composer.lock>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files .gitignore>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files .htaccess>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files .htaccess.sample>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files .php_cs>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files .travis.yml>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files CHANGELOG.md>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files CONTRIBUTING.md>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files CONTRIBUTOR_LICENSE_AGREEMENT.html>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files COPYING.txt>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files Gruntfile.js>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files LICENSE.txt>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files LICENSE_AFL.txt>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files nginx.conf.sample>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files package.json>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files php.ini.sample>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files README.md>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>

################################
## If running in cluster environment, uncomment this
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags

    #FileETag none
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue recently and couldn't find what was causing it at all.

That was until I checked the `debug.log` - it turned out to be a syntax error in my theme's custom LESS file. (In my case I'd added an extra bracket somewhere).

- I fixed the error
- Deployed static files again
- Cleaned and flushed the cache

I refreshed the page again and the theme was processing properly.

I'm not sure why Magento threw a wobbler over that - it could be the setup of my site, but hey - it solved it so I know for next time!

Hope this helps others :)

Answer (score 1):

download a fresh .htaccess file from the official repo [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2)

https://github.com/magento/magento2

and replace or add in it pub/static

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of this error, I removed the CSS snippet from

> Admin Panel -> Content > Design > Configuration > Select Theme > HTML Head section > Scripts and Style Sheets

Then you can proceed. Since that file is never gonna be used in magento :)

Comment: What CSS Snipet was causing this?? The field is already empty on a fresh magento 2.

Comment: Thank you! for me it was link text/css media all href media url styles.css . 
after removing that theme started working well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your theme in that file: dev/tools/grunt/configs/themes.js

Answer (score 0):

In my case this problem appeared after I deleted a less variable which was still used in other less files.

Therefore Magento did not complete the compilation of the css which results in another server response as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If (for some reason) you are using a **theme from Venustheme** the CSS file isn't getting created during a content deploy. There is an error in Chrome about unsupported MIME types, but when you check on FTP the file doesn't even exist.

To fix it go to:

```
Venustheme -> Customization -> and click Save Config
```

Clear cache after that and it will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

same problem I've had just today. Whatever I've done I could not resolve.
I could not reach admin since CSS was not loading...

The I figured out from Google page information, itr can not find the css files under /pub/static. I checked the .htaccess files for all directories, all was fine.

I saw it was searching for .css files but I checked then with cpanel file explorer, that place I have .min.css.

SO I understand this is because of the minification setting in admin for CSS and JS.

**Before I checked all to YES for JSS and CSS merge and minification.**

Since I could not reach admin, I opened phpMyadmin and find **core_config_data** table and make search **PATH = %LIKE%** css and then js and make minification and merge set to "0" back.

then I make again:

- > bin/magento s:d:c
- > bin/magento setup:static-content deploy -f (tr_TR for my language)
- > bin/magento c:f
- > bin/magento c:c

all is fine and this problem resolved for me...

hope this helps someone facing same case like me...

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error in my local setup. So I tried

1. grunt clean;
2. bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

At the time of static content deploy I come to know that there is some wrong variable assignment in _theme.less. I fixed that and again ran

1. grunt clean;
2. bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

This fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I noticed that the normal CSS was being called on the page and, previously, I enabled the reduction of the size of the CSS, to solve, duplicated the CSS files and removed the ".min" from them:

example.min.css
example.css

leaving the two files in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

I'll just add that I had this error when my style sheet file was empty, and it went away once I added css to it.

Answer (score 0):

I got this bug as I tried to use mixins and variables from my theme in one of my custom modules at **app/code/Company/Contact/css/source/_module.less**

I executed `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy de_DE` (<-- replace `de_DE` by your language code, e.g. `en_US`)

then It was showing me some errors leading to the problem:

> Compilation from source:
> /home/company/company.de/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/styles-l.less
> .h1 is undefined in
> /home/company/company.de/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/Company_Contact/css/source/_module.less
>
> Compilation from source:
> /home/company/company.de/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/styles-m.less
> .h1 is undefined in
> /home/company/company.de/var/view_preprocessed

I had to remove the mixins, since I can't use them here.

Answer (score 0):

make sure pub/static and all subfolders/files in them have 777 permission. Once done redeploy static content with

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Answer (score 0):

delete pub\static
run php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento c:f

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your apache configuration this in your root directory can save your life...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pub/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/setup/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/update/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dev/
RewriteRule .* /pub/$0 [L]
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the given answers I would also suggest to check if the following configs have been set correctly in `core_config_data` table (or directly in the backoffice):

> *web/unsecure/base_url*
>
> *web/secure/base_url*
>
> *web/unsecure/base_url*
>
> *web/secure/base_url*
>
> *admin/url/custom*

To recap then, what I usually do when this specific issue happens to me is  following these steps:

1. check whether or not you have the .htaccess file in the
   `pub/static` folder
2. try with: *`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`*
3. take a look to the following configs:

> - *web/unsecure/base_url*
> - *web/secure/base_url*
> - *web/unsecure/base_url*
> - *web/secure/base_url*
> - *admin/url/custom*

4. go brute on the cache and *`php bin/magento cache:flush`*

Answer (score -2):

My problem was owner permissions, some of the files were shifted from my account to the `root` account.

After seeing there were too many files to be changed, I just changed ownership for the whole `www` folder as I have only one Magento.

```bash
chown yourusername:yourusername -R /home/<yourusername>/www/*
```

Comment: This answer is very dependent of what user/file permissions your server runs under. This answers will most often than not, ruin installs where the server runs under www-data.

Comment: Thank you! FYI: for default installation folder, I used: chown -R www-data: /var/www/magento

Answer (score -2):

El tratado todas las soluciones aportadas por varios sitios sin solución. Finalmente el problema estaba en los archivos de sesión.
Por un error en mi servidor plesk modifique el directorio de almacenamiento de sesión en env.php al directorio var / sessions en mi raid de magento.
Modifique los permisos en mi servidor para el almacenamiento de sesion y restarure env.php para configurar nuevamente las sesiones en el directorio de mi servidor e inmediatamente se corrigio el problema. Espero le sirva a alguien o de luz a algun problema similar.