# How to fix its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type error in magento 2.3?

Tags: magento2.3

Magento Version: 2.3.0

As per my client requirement, I was upgraded Magento 2.3.0 from 2.2.6.

All functionality works properly but always show the following error into inspecting element console.

[image]

Please suggest me how can I fix it into Magento version 2.3?

Comment: check if the .htaccess file is inside pub/static folder

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue,

1. Go to file path **`pub/static/`**
2. Check whether the **`.htaccess`** file is available (hidden file - Press ctrl+H to view it).
3. If not available, you can [download](https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.3-develop/pub/static) .htaccess file in the file path **pub/static/** and move it into your server.
4. Finally, clear your browser and Magento cache and check again.

Another way if `.htaccess` is present in pub/static folder try ro redeploy static view files by running:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Comment: Thanks for reply,

I tried above solution and it's not working well still showing above error.

Comment: I run into the same issue today and found out that I was using a different language locale which I need to redeploy first and it works

Comment: That also tried but not working.

Because in my client's website used four languages and i already tried to ran static deploy commands for different language.

But still same error occurred.

Comment: have you check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/212514/refused-to-apply-style-because-its-mime-type-text-html-is-not-a-supported-s