# My control admin not load :(

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, magento2.3, windows

My control admin of magento not load (it looks white). I tried several things how example: delete cache and with other explorers, etc... and really i need help because with this i tried 15 times.

I have XAMP 7.2 and Magento 2.3, windows 8.1

Comment: check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/269104/magento-2-3-1-is-not-working-in-xampp/269111#269111

Answer (score 0):

This may help you to debug it:

Add below code in top of the `index.php` file of magento root, then look for the error

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

Also, please check the log files.

Comment: How i see the log files? sorry for the question....

Comment: magento_root/var/log/ , var/report , check exception logs

Comment: I am there... but appears: HTML, node, Clover.php, factory.php, HTML.php,Node.php,PHP.php,text.php

Comment: in the var log folder?

Comment: Look this: main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'E:/xampp/htdocs/Magento/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/templates/logger.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Ui' block's name: 'logger'

Comment: I showme this in the log

Comment: Maybe this will help you : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/251926/magento-2-3-its-not-working-properly-in-localhost#answer-251999 , (you can also try to disable some extension and check it)

Comment: Nothing :( i try and nothing

Comment: can you please view source of that blank page?

Comment: Yeah, and i open the console in the page (inspect element) and appears this:

Comment: Refused to apply style from '<URL>' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Comment: and this: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/212514/refused-to-apply-style-because-its-mime-type-text-html-is-not-a-supported-s#answer-267448