# Magento 2 Css and images are not loading in production mode

Tags: magento2, css, product-images

I've have changed mode from developer to production,then cleared cache,deployed but `css` and images are not showing . Image's status is 404 and stylesheet's `Refused to apply style from because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.`

what should i do? Searched a lot but not didnt get any good result :(

Comment: Refer this link : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/212514/refused-to-apply-style-because-its-mime-type-text-html-is-not-a-supported-s

Answer (score 2):

Please try by running this command:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f en_US
```

`en_US` please change it with your store country code.

Comment: Thank you for reply, but still not working.. :(

Comment: Try to apply production mode command:

php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production

Answer (score 1):

Recently had a very similar issue with a Magento 2 site. Managed to track down the issue to a very important `.htaccess` file missing in the `pub/static` folder on the server.

It's unclear how this file was mysteriously removed but re-adding this file from a clean Magento 2 installation rectified the issue.