# Does ANYONE run Magento 2 on Windows 7?

Tags: magento2, windows

I have asked many times and whilst some answers are well meaning haven't got this working yet. I hate to  post a "bump" message (in fact this is my first, ever) and but this seems such a basic question. Either it won't work, I am doing something wrong, I haven't asked in the right place (or the right way) or I need new aftershave.

Here are the unanswered questions:

https://community.magento.com/t5/Installing-Magento-2/Cannot-install-Magento-2-on-Windows-7-localhost-using-XAMPP/m-p/48777#U48777

[Why does the web based install of Magento 2 on Windows 7 localhost using XAMPP always fail?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139054/why-does-the-web-based-install-of-magento-2-on-windows-7-localhost-using-xampp-a)

[Magento 2 CSS and JavaScript not loading from correct folder](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97209/magento-2-css-and-javascript-not-loading-from-correct-folder?rq=1)

Comment: Sort of. Windows 2008 R2 Server and actually fairly happy with how it runs. There were a few oddities but overall it's pretty good

Comment: I'm trying with Windows 7. Can I ask how you installed it please?

Comment: Used the web installer on Windows Server to install PHP and then just installed it normally. The DB is on a different machine.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I'm using 7. I would recommend against using xampp with m2 because even when you do get it working, it's too slow. I've had the best results using a vagrant box from Alan Kent available here https://alankent.me/2016/06/03/magento-2-development-with-windows-and-vagrant/

Comment: Thanks. I'm very familiar with the VM approach, and this looks a worthy variant. The problem is we have Windows only users, content producers, graphics/web designers (not devs) and testers using various laptop/desktop rigs, and they are all using straight localhost based XAMPP setups for the other CMS's like Joomla etc. I don't want to have to support VM installs as well, just for this. Why can't Magento just tell everyone Mangento 2 doesn't work on Windows? It's not really a loss when you know this - it certainly is when you wast so much time trying and it still fails.

Comment: I see. If it's any help, I got magento 2 working in xampp by making a change to the file app/etc/di.xml. In line 607, change `Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink` to `Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy`.

Comment: Sincere thanks for your help Aaron. If you check the second link above you'll see I did that - but can you spot in there anything else you did differently?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is it is not supported:
http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/magento/system-requirements.html

Comment: that doesn't mean it's not possible^^

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami have pre-built free Magento 2 installers for native Windows and as VM images. They're quite fast.

https://bitnami.com/stack/magento/installer

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2.x is not supported Windows OS and Mac OS due security reasons however we can still install Magento 2 on Windows machine using XAMPP tool, but we must fix some known errors after installing on Windows system. 
Check this link for more details. 
https://www.howtoinmagento.com/2019/06/magento-2x-does-not-support-windows-mac.html