# Magento 2 css/js/urls not working after change domain name

Tags: admin, javascript, css, magento-2.1.3, domain

After changing domain name css js and links admin are not working in my site **http://www.shopbrow.com/** i have change the base url and secure url and clean the cache folder after changing it but its not work
After that i have followed the following tutorial 
[Magento 2 CSS and JavaScript not loading from correct folder](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97209/magento-2-css-and-javascript-not-loading-from-correct-folder)

its also not working for me can any one help me

Comment: Which wrong folder you are seeing in view source ?

Comment: @ Kishan Patadia this is my site url can you please check it shopbrow.com there the folders and styles are in the path but its not showing while click on the url

Comment: /pub/static/version1496046040/frontend/Mobac/porto/en_US/mage/calendar.css  heare when i remove /version1496046040 i can access the style sheet

Comment: first backup of url_rewrite table and url rewrite generate. and then php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Answer (score 1):

Run following query in database

```
INSERT INTO `core_config_data` (`scope`, `scope_id`, `path`, `value`) VALUES ('default', 0, 'dev/static/sign', '0');
```

or if you have already value for that path, then change it from **1** to **0**.

Then flush cache and deploy static content as follows.

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: I have followed this but same result no changes