# Rewrite not working CSS not loaded, module enabled

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, migration, mod-rewrite

**CSS**, **scripts** not loading, via pub/static/version1496086766/frontend/Magento/, but loading without version: pub/static/frontend/Magento/..
There is .htaccess file with rewrite rule, and  sudo a2enmod rewrite - 
Module rewrite already enabled, and I have set AllowOverride: 

SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
AllowOverride All

I have set up apache virtual host with webmin.
This problem is coming after migration, I have copied the backup and db to another server. Website is working, but CSS is not loaded.

Comment: check this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97209/magento-2-css-and-javascript-not-loading-from-correct-folder/97230#97230

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run following query in database

```
INSERT INTO `core_config_data` (`scope`, `scope_id`, `path`, `value`) VALUES ('default', 0, 'dev/static/sign', '0');
```

or if you have already value for that path, then change it from **1** to **0**.

Then flush cache and deploy static content as follows.

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```