# How can I get the stylesheet to load?

Tags: magento2, installation, styles

I have installed a fresh Magento2 but style sheet is not loading  and When I
check the page source, the style sheet isn't there, and of course, the
page looks terrible:

http://unisolinternational.magemojo.io/

It has the `ClickBoom theme by Magentech`, and I used their "`quickstart`" to install Magento and the theme all at once.

Here's what I've already tried:

- deployed content, set the pub
- directory to 777` confirmed I have a "/" at the end of the URL
- replaced the .htaccess files with sample .htaccess files.

I appreciate any suggestions you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing problem of css and js page load design after installation in magento2

please follow the following step-:

open the terminal and navigate to magento web root

```
  $ cd /var/www/html/magento2
```

**Step 1.**

```
  $ php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

**Step 2.**

```
  $ php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

**Step 3.**

```
  make sure apache “rewrite_module” is enable and then restart the server
```

**Step 4.**

```
   $ chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/magento2
```

**Step 5.**

```
   $ chmod -R 775 /var/www/html/magento2/ 
   $ chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/magento2/var/
   $ chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/magento2/pub/
```

**Step 6.**

```
  delete cache folder under var/cache
```

The above step working. I hope this will work for you also.

You can check following useful links aswell:  answer is already given there.

[Magento 2 CSS and JavaScript not loading from correct folder](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97209/magento-2-css-and-javascript-not-loading-from-correct-folder)

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/trouble/tshoot_no-styles.html

https://community.magento.com/t5/Installing-Magento-2/CSS-not-loading-in-the-front-and-backend-after-installing-via/td-p/22786

Comment: Thank you for that advice.  Unfortunately, I don't have the option to restart the server, because the website is on shared hosting.