# Magento2: Default layout changed, Admin and front end

Tags: magento2, layout

I am new to Magento. I am building a new eCommerce website for our company, which sells thousand of products. I have installed Magento2.1.12 via xampp yesterday and started configuring the site. After setting up Stores - Configuration - Web; Unsecure and secure links, the Magento admin panel and front end layouts have completely changed. It looks as if CSS is not working i.e. no styling both in admin panel and front end. Does anyone know what have I done wrong and how to retrieve the default settings back?

Here are the screenshots for Admin panel and folder structure.

[image]

[image]

Your help would be appreciated!
TIA!

Comment: Execute this command one by one: `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`. After execute `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`. I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Clean the content folder of `pub/static`, `var/cache`, `var/page_cache`, `var/view_preprocessed` except the `.htaccess`
2. Launch this command : `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

You can find more informations [here.](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/97230/48355)

Comment: Thank you for the responses! @Prince, I have followed what you've suggested but after <your Magento install dir>/bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f command I am getting "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect" error. I am unable to figure out the cause and solution for the same. Can you please suggest a solution? Thanks!

Comment: You have to execute this command in the root project location

Comment: My root directory(Magento2) is under htdocs. Hence the path is: C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento2>cd bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f. Which gave me the same error as I mentioned earlier. Do you think if the symbol such as, semi-colon or space has an issue?

Comment: not `cd` but `php`

Comment: when I gave 'php' here is what I got:  'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: try `sudo php ...`

Comment: Tried sudo php ... here is what I got: C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento2>sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
'sudo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: you havent the php command installed in your server, you have to install it

Comment: This is where the php is located: C:\xampp\php. Is that what you are suggesting?

Comment: http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Run-a-PHP-Script-With-Wamp-Server/

Comment: I have followed the steps mentioned above, still no luck. There's no layout :(