# Magento CSS Not Loading Error

Tags: magento2, css, static-content

I have tried every suggestion that is out there but im still getting this error
[image]

In my config data they are figured as:

[image]

i have tried the solutions none of them are working im still getting the same error over and over.
I also have apache rewrite mode on as well.

I have tried:

[Magento 2 CSS and JavaScript not loading from correct folder](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97209/magento-2-css-and-javascript-not-loading-from-correct-folder)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34040496/magento-2-not-loading-css-and-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `web/unsecure/base_static_url` and `web/secure/base_static_url` as `http://localhost/tfgs-m2/pub/static/` OR remove this entry from `core_config_data` table and flush cache.

Comment: Now i am getting 500 (Internal Server Error), any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: just flush cache and try after static content deploy.

Comment: still getting the same error

Comment: what you changed?

Comment: i did "just flush cache and try after static content deploy."

Comment: I mean did you changed as `http://localhost/tfgs-m2/pub/static/` or removed `base_static_url` from `core_config_data` table

Comment: i changed it as "http://localhost/tfgs-m2/pub/static/"

Comment: ok, add this code `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` in `vendor/autoload.php`. also check `pub/static/` folder exist in your root magento.

Comment: i did still didnt fix

Comment: do you get any error text?  and I think `pub/static` folders are exist.

Comment: im not getting any errors, pub/static exists as well

Comment: is there any folders in that `pub/static`? do you have M2.1 OR 2.2?

Comment: There are folders, 2.2 i am using

Comment: Ok try after delete `web/unsecure/base_static_url` and `web/secure/base_static_url` entry from `core_config_data` table. also confirm that `static.php` exist in your 'pub' folder

Comment: still didnt work, i have done everything you said

Comment: Is 'static.php' file exist?

Comment: yea ,its there...

Comment: ok, now delete `cache` folder and delete `frontend` and `adminhtml` from `pub/static/` folder then re run `php bin/magento setup:static:deploy nl_NL -f`

Comment: @CompuScie please try this.

Comment: tried man still doesnt work :(

Comment: I think you have the issue related to folder permission or server configuration. Please what URL you getting.

Comment: what do you mean by "what url you are getting" i have given access to the folders

Comment: I mean you getting `/static/version1528266198/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/css/styles-l.css` URL or `/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/css/styles-l.css`?

Comment: Also may I know your server and OS?

Comment: i am using xamp , windows and `/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/css/styles-l.css`

Comment: I am sure it is related to `.htaccess` file please check this link https://community.magento.com/t5/Installing-Magento-2-x/CSS-and-JS-files-not-loaded-after-installation-Wamp64/m-p/95964/highlight/true#M4190

Comment: i cant explain how thankfull i am, i was going nuts, comment on the other post ill give you a plus as well

Comment: ahh finally, we got the solution, welcome happy to help you

Comment: Helpful @Kunj! Saves alot of time. Thank you much!

Answer (score 2):

What was your deployment command? it should have `nl_NL` so should be something like: `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy nl_NL -f`

if you did please insure the files are physically existing under `pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/nl_NL` folder

if they're, check for the existence of `.htaccess` under `/pub/static/`

Answer (score 0):

rename .htaccess to bkp.htaccess  in pub folder.

or clean cache we can

rename because in developing model Magento can't set all condition and  permissions that's why to change the name of this file.