# Probleme of css and javascript not working on server amazon magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have put my project on server amazon and i get no css none javascript and i tried every sol in stack but still not working please advice me to fix this issue thanks

Comment: did you go through this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97209/magento-2-css-and-javascript-not-loading-from-correct-folder?

Comment: have you check the css and js url in firbug i think there would be like staticversion showing in urls instead of direct pub/static path can you please check?

Comment: http://ec2-35-165-167-215.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/site/pub/static/version1543489755/adminhtml/Sm/shop4u/fr_FR/jquery/jstree/themes/default/style.css  giving 404 not found

Comment: ok go into pub/static directory and check is .htaccess there or not?

Comment: yes i can see this file

Comment: and in root directory also check

Comment: yes  , it's there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86378/discussion-between-developper-magento-and-charul-tyagi).