# Wrong path to js, css and image file when installing magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, installation, js-css

I have just installed  Magento 2.3. Now when I fire it up, the CSS and JS is not loading.

I looked at the source and it always has the version of the deployment in the path, like

> /pub/static/version1484648587/frontend/... . This does not exist
>   though, I only have /pub/static/frontend. even with command line
>   bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f, path indicated is not
>   correct.

please help

Comment: Please see this solution: [click here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97209/magento-2-css-and-javascript-not-loading-from-correct-folder) Hope this will help you! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The path `/pub/static/version1484648587/frontend/` is only a virtual path which would only visible on browser

The path `/pub/static/frontend` is the actual path which is created after your deployment script.

This is not an issue or bug, when browser calls any js or css from static version path then the file calls from `/pub/static/frontend/..` path, you don't need to worry about this.

Check documentation for details: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cache/static-content-signing.html

Comment: These are valid comments, however this does not help the OP main issue which is CSS and JS not loading