# Magento 2.3: After install Magento by CLI not work upgrade command

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, upgrade, installation

After Install Magento2.3 by cli and when try upgrade command getting below Error:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

> The directory "generated/code/Magento/Backend/App/Request" cannot be deleted Warning!rmdir(generated/code/Magento/Backend/App/Request): Directory not empty The directory "generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/ResourceModel" cannot be deleted Warning!rmdir(generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/ResourceModel): Directory not empty The directory "generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Ui/DataProvider" cannot be deleted Warning!rmdir(generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Ui/DataProvider): Directory not empty The directory "generated/code/Magento/CatalogSearch/Model/ResourceModel/Fulltext" cannot be deleted Warning!rmdir(generated/code/Magento/CatalogSearch/Model/ResourceModel/Fulltext): Directory not empty The directory "generated/code/Magento/Directory/Helper" cannot be deleted Warning!rmdir(generated/code/Magento/Directory/Helper): Directory not empty The directory "generated/code/Magento/Eav/Model/Adminhtml/System/Config" cannot be deleted Warning!rmdir(generated/code/Magento/Eav/Model/Adminhtml/System/Config): Directory not empty The directory "generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Config" cannot be deleted Warning!rmdir(generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Config): Directory not empty The directory "generated/code/Magento/Framework/Data/Argument" cannot be deleted Warning!rmdir(generated/code/Magento/Framework/Data/Argument): Directory not empty The directory "generated/code/Magento/Framework/Event/Config" cannot be deleted Warning!rmdir(generated/code/Magento/Framework/Event/Config): Directory not empty The directory "generated/code/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/Config/Reader" cannot be deleted Warning!rmdir(generated/code/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/Config/Reader): Directory not empty The directory "generated/code/Magento/Framework/Session/Config" cannot be deleted Warning!rmdir(generated/code/Magento/Framework/Session/Config): Directory not empty The directory "generated/code/Magento/Swatches/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Attribute" cannot be deleted Warning!rmdir(generated/code/Magento/Swatches/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Attribute): Directory not empty The directory "generated/code/Magento/Ui/Config" cannot be deleted Warning!rmdir(generated/code/Magento/Ui/Config): Directory not empty

Any one can help me for this. I have already set write/read all permission.

Comment: delete your generated folder and try it will work

Comment: do you means generated root folder or var/generated folder..?

Comment: var/generated folder

Comment: inside var folder not have any generated folder.

Comment: sorry you are using mage2.3 ver so you should delete root generated folder.But make sure don't delete .htaccess inside this folder

Comment: ok,let me rename to generated/code folder to generated/@code so .htaccess file will remain inside this folder.

Comment: no, still not working..frontend and backend not load css and js.
I have follow this linkhttps://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97209/magento-2-css-and-javascript-not-loading-from-correct-folder

Comment: @SangeetaChandaliya check the folder and file ownership.

Answer (score 1):

Try below steps:-

```
sudo rm -rf var/*
sudo rm -rf pub/static/frontend/*
sudo rm -rf generated/*

sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/(project name)/
sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
sudo php bin/magento ca:cl
sudo php bin/magento ca:fl
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/(project name)/
```

Hope this will help you..!

Comment: delete your generated a folder and then try to upgrade command

Comment: Not working..CSS/JS is not load on frontend/backend

Answer (score 1):

When using windows and you have installed GIT then you have a option to run some linux command over windows using `GIT BASH`

Open `GIT BASH` using right click from your root folder and try to run below command

```
 rm -rf var/*
 rm -rf pub/static/frontend/*
 rm -rf generated/code/*

 chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/(project name)/
 php bin/magento setup:upgrade
 php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
 php bin/magento ca:cl
 php bin/magento ca:fl
 chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/(project name)/
```

> CSS/JS is not load on frontend/backend

for this check `pub` folder `.htacess` files and find the code like `IfVersion` and delete.

Comment: Not working..CSS/JS is not load on frontend/backend

Comment: updated answer please check.

Answer (score 0):

The command 'del' or 'rmdir' will remove the recursive directories based on your OS edition.

Ref: https://superuser.com/questions/179660/how-to-recursively-delete-directory-from-command-line-in-windows