# CSS is not coming on Magento 2 Frontend

Tags: magento2, css

Now my CSS Link are  **https://www.vdcprojects.xyz/otabazzar/version1596944524/frontend/Sm/topmart/en_US/css/styles-m.css**

Actually CSS are in :
**https://www.vdcprojects.xyz/otabazzar/pub/static/frontend/Sm/topmart/en_US/css/styles-m.css**

I have also have `.htaccess` file in pub/static folder and also give `pemission 777` to all folder and file.

But css is not loading how to solve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is to follow the link below and read it have all possible thing which makes CSS unload properly

[Magento 2 CSS and JavaScript not loading from correct folder](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97209/magento-2-css-and-javascript-not-loading-from-correct-folder)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you run following command once

```
php bin/magneto setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

and than check if **`mod_rewrite`** is enabled or not in apache

Comment: i run a command also chk the mod_rewrite is enable but my css is not loading

Comment: Can you check ownership of pub folder

Answer (score 0):

Please go to database table **core_config_data**

Please check **path** field with **web/unsecure/base_static_url** and **web/secure/base_static_url**

If you get this data in this table then fill the **value** field with below data

```
https://www.vdcprojects.xyz/otabazzar/pub/static/
```

Then run this below command and check

**php bin/magneto setup:static-content:deploy -f**